# Firebase A/B Test - same userId on different devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

Does Firebase A/B testing take into consideration user id which is set by `FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId`? Here is my use case:

1. `John Doe` opens the app
2. He signs in
3. `FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId` is called with `johnDoeUserId`
4. Remote config values are fetched -> **he lands in `VariantA`**
5. `John Doe` opens the app on a different device (same Google account)
6. He signs in
7. `FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId` is called with `johnDoeUserId`
8. Remote config values are fetched -> **is it guaranteed that he is going to land in `VariantA`**?

Does `userId` has any meaning for A/B test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not guaranteed. The ID that will be used takes the device into account, so it is possible for the same user to be in two different variants across devices.

Comment: does Firebase have any plans to support this?